# Php Unset not deleting array elements

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I'm going through csv files and am trying to delete elements in 2 arrays (matchingFields &fieldstolookfor) as I find their elements in a csv.

```
public function addRecords($dealerFeedsDirectory, $vin)
    {
        $files = glob($dealerFeedsDirectory . "*.csv");
        $fieldsToLookFor = array("dealername", "dealeraddress", "dealerstate", "year", "make", "model", "phone", "url");
        $fieldsFound = array();
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if(empty($fieldsToLookFor)) {
                break;
            }
            echo "File We are Looking through : " . $file , "<br>";
            echo "Fields left : ";
            print_r($fieldsToLookFor);
            echo " <br>";
            $fp = fopen($file, 'r');
            $csvReader = new CSVReader($fp, ',');
            if ($fieldNames = $csvReader->readHeader()) {
                //print_r( $fieldNames);
                $matchingFields = array();
                foreach ($fieldNames as $fieldName) {
                    if (in_array($fieldName, $fieldsToLookFor)) {
                        $matchingFields[] = $fieldName;
                    }
                }
                //print_r($matchingFields);

                while (($row = $csvReader->readRow()) !== false && !empty($matchingFields)) {
                    if ($row[Constants::VIN] == $vin) {
                        foreach ($matchingFields as $matchingField) {
                            $fieldsFound[$matchingField] = $row[$matchingField];
                            print_r( $matchingFields);echo  "matchingfields <br>";
                            print_r( $fieldsToLookFor);echo  "fieldstolookfor <br>";
                            unset($matchingFields[$matchingField]);
                            unset($fieldsToLookFor[$matchingField]);
                        }
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        print_r($fieldsFound);
    }
```

Items are being deleted from the $matchingFields array but not the $fieldsToLookFor (fieldsToLookfor should also have 5 items) array after going through one csv file. Why is this?

```
Array ( [0] => url [1] => make [2] => model [3] => year [4] => phone ) matchingfields
Array ( [0] => dealername [1] => dealeraddress [2] => dealerstate [3] => year [4] => make [5] => model [6] => phone [7] => url ) fieldstolookfor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this `unset`:

```
unset($fieldsToLookFor[$matchingField]);
```

you're trying to unset a key in the `$fieldsToLookFor` array like 'model' or 'url', which are its values, not its keys. (The keys are 0, 1, etc.)

In fact, it doesn't look like you would be deleting items from `$matchingFields` either for the same reason. It seems more likely that those were the only values added to `$matchingFields` in the earlier `foreach ($fieldNames as $fieldName)` loop.

---

An easy way to make this work without making many changes would be to use the fields as keys as well as values. Like this before the outer loop:

```
$fieldsToLookFor = array_combine($fieldsToLookFor, $fieldsToLookFor);
foreach ($files as $file){ ...
```

Then also later when you set `$matchingFields`:

```
if (in_array($fieldName, $fieldsToLookFor)) {
    $matchingFields[$fieldName] = $fieldName;
}
```